# Store an object in an ngModel with a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I'm working with angularjs for some weeks now, and I don't get what the angularjs designers thought when designing the $viewValue and $modelValue functionality from the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController). Code example:

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="PlunkerApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <listfield ng-model="termList"></listfield>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
var plunkerModule = angular.module('PlunkerApp', []);

plunkerModule.directive('listfield', function() {
  'use strict';
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
    console.log('listfield.link():', scope);
    ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
      console.log('listfield.model.parser:', value);
      return value ? value.join(', ') : undefined;

    });
    ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value) {
      console.log('listfield.model.formatter:', value);
      return value ? value.split(/,\s*/) : undefined;
    });
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="ngModel">'
  };
});

plunkerModule.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.termList = "";
  $scope.$watchCollection('termList', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('mainController.watch.list:', newValue);
  });
});
```

plunker link:
http://plnkr.co/edit/T5a8zEQuRyYWnpsZZV9W?p=preview

So in this application the value from the directives input element is written into the global scope, which works fine! My problem is, I'm not interested in the "raw" string value, i want the array that is generated by the formatter but the input element should still show the string value.

How can I do that??

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Interesting, there seem to be two ngModelControllers created in that snippet, with the *second one* (which doesn't have your formatters/parsers) being called when the model value is updated.

Comment: Which would mean that the input "ng-model" attribute has to be removed and that I have to handle all events (keydown, blur, watch on model) myself and angularjs is no help for me =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that both your `<input>` and your `<listfield>` tags have an ngModel, confusing which one is called when. You can use the `replace: true` option for your directive to remove the `<listfield>` tag and work only with the `<input>`, like so:

```
var plunkerModule = angular.module('PlunkerApp', []);

plunkerModule.directive('listfield', function() {
  'use strict';
  var link = function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
    console.log('listfield.link():', scope);
    // Your formatters and parsers seemed to be the other way around
    // The formatter transforms Model -> View
    // Whereas the parser transforms View -> Model
    ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(value) {
      console.log('listfield.model.formatter:', value);
      return value ? value.join(', ') : undefined;

    });
    ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(value) {
      console.log('listfield.model.parser:', value);
      return value ? value.split(/,\s*/) : undefined;
    });
  }
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: link,
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true, // Removes the <listfield> tag
    scope: {
      model: '='
    },
    template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model">'
  };
});

plunkerModule.controller('mainController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.termList = [1,2,3]
  $scope.$watchCollection('termList', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log('mainController.watch.list:', newValue);
  });
  $timeout(function changeTermList() { $scope.termList = [4,5,6]}, 2000)
  // This is to demonstrate the binding used via the isolate scope(=)
});
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
  <body ng-app="PlunkerApp" ng-controller="mainController">
    <listfield model="termList"></listfield>
  </body>
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/G0tlC9qhW8AHa58yVSgj?p=preview

Comment: Nice! New to me is that the ngModelController is injected although there was no ng-model specified.. So that ngModelController is an own isolated instance for that directive? I tried to use the same model for two input fields in the template like here: http://plnkr.co/edit/VHHxjc20ZDnyii52dzjN?p=preview which works but drops error message: "Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'listfield', can't be found!". You have an idea for that?

Comment: `require` looks for a directive "ng-model" on the same element(`<listfield>`) or its parents - since there's no such directive, you get that error. But when you use replace, there's no `<listfield>` element at all.

Comment: Thanks =) is there a way to bind the ng-model to an html element that is not the first one? For example: '<div><input type="text"></div>'.